# Using appcmd to add a new site without supplying site id?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, iis-7, batch-file

I'm writing a batch script to deploy web sites packaged with Visual Studio 2010. In the script, I'm adding new sites as such:

`appcmd add site /name:MySite /id:123`

However, I don't want to specify a site id. I would just like `appcmd` to randomly assign one for me. But the `id` parameter is required for `appcmd`, so how do I go around about it?

Comment: FYI: If you have built an actual website deployment package using the "Build Deployment Package" functionality within Visual Studio 2010, it should contain all of the IIS settings and an installation batch script for you. Have you considered using that feature?

Comment: @Cory, I did. But that one doesn't work. It keep saying MS Deploy wasn't installed even it is installed. When I specify a path for the MSDeployPath variable, it bombed at the first `for` loop. The generated script has `@rem set MSDeployPath="C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\"` so I changed it to `set MSDeployPath="C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V2\"` but it bombed at the `for` loop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've never known the /id param to be required - I've always used the form:

```
appcmd add site /name:"%appName%" /bindings:http://%appDns%:80 /physicalPath:"%mainApplicationPath%"
```

And never had any problems. What error is appcmd giving you when you don't specify it?

Comment: looks like it works without supplying the id. but the doc at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772350(v=ws.10).aspx, said: "The variable name string is the name, and the variable id uint is the unsigned integer that you want to assign to the site. The variables name string and id uint are the only variables that are required when you add a site in Appcmd.exe." oh well...

Comment: Always nice to have accurate documentation!

Answer (score 3):

Use appcmd help, type

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD add site /?
```

And you will see that only name parameter is required, here is the part of that output:

> [w:\kanta]%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD add site /? Add new
>   virtual site
>
> APPCMD add SITE  <-parameter1:value1 ...>
>
> Creates a new virtual site with the specified settings.  At minimum,
>   the site name and id must be provided.
>
> Supported parameters:
>
> /name (required)
>
> ```
> Site name
> ```
>
> /id
>
> ```
> Site id
> ```
>
> /bindings
>
> ```
> List of bindings in the friendly form of "http://domain:port,..." or raw
> form of "protocol/bindingInformation,..."
> ```
>
> /physicalPath
>
> ```
> If specified, will cause the root application containing a root virtual
> directory pointing to the specified path to be created for this site.  If
> omitted, the site is created without a root application and will not be
> startable until one is created.
> ```
>
> /?
>
> ```
> Display the dynamic site properties that can be set on the new site
> ```